# How do I utilize string "*" or "\" as mathematical operators?

Tags: vb.net, math

I want to use "*" or "\" as  mathematical operators as such:

**"I am going to clarify"**

```
dim tbox as textbox
tbox.text = "*"

dim i as integer = 8 tbox.text 3
```

**"End Clarify"**

```
dim [mult] as string = "*"
dim [div] as string = "\"


dim i as integer = 8 [mult] 3
```

and the result would be i is equal to 24

or

```
dim i as integer = 8 [div] 2
```

and the result would be i is equal to 4

Can anyone solve this in one line without building a long, complex function?  I would also like for this to be something that is already a part of the VB.NET structure and doesn't require an import.

If such a solution does not exist how do I do it with a function or .dll import?

Comment: Do you want to change the syntax of VB.NET? What is wrong with writing `8*3` and `8\2` in code which is perfectly legal VB.NET?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with writing 8*3 if I weren't trying to read the operand from a textbox, i have editted my question for clarification purposes.

Comment: “without building a long, complex function” => **No.** For the record, that is an unreasonable requirement. What you want, if done right, is an incredibly complex bit of logic.

Comment: I thought as much.  I didn't see a simple method of completing this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Insert This into where you want to evaluate.

```
dim [mult] as string = "*"
dim [div] as string = "\"


'dim i as integer = 8 [mult] 3

op = mult

dim i As Integer = Eval("8" & op & "3")

'i is your result


  Private Function Eval(ByVal command As String) As Object
    Dim MyProvider As New VBCodeProvider 'Create a new VB Code Compiler
    Dim cp As New CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters     'Create a new Compiler parameter object.

    cp.GenerateExecutable = False        'Don't create an object on disk
    cp.GenerateInMemory = True           'But do create one in memory.

    'If cp.OutputAssembly is used with a VBCodeProvider, it seems to want to read before it is executed. 

    'See C# CodeBank example for explanation of why it was used.



    'the below is an empty VB.NET Project with a function that simply returns the value of our command parameter.

    Dim ClassName As String = "class" & Now.Ticks

    Dim TempModuleSource As String = "Imports System" & Environment.NewLine & _
                                     "Namespace ns " & Environment.NewLine & _
                                     "    Public Class " & ClassName & Environment.NewLine & _
                                     "        Public Shared Function Evaluate()" & Environment.NewLine & _
                                     "            Return (" & command & ")" & Environment.NewLine & _
                                     "        End Function" & Environment.NewLine & _
                                     "    End Class" & Environment.NewLine & _
                                     "End Namespace"

    'Create a compiler output results object and compile the source code.

    Dim cr As CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerResults = MyProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(cp, TempModuleSource)

    If cr.Errors.Count > 0 Then

      'If the expression passed is invalid or "", the compiler will generate errors.

      'Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Invalid Expression - please use something VB could evaluate")
      Return Nothing
    Else

      'Find our Evaluate method.
      Dim methInfo As Reflection.MethodInfo = cr.CompiledAssembly.GetType("ns." & ClassName).GetMethod("Evaluate")

      'Invoke it on nothing, so that we can get the return value
      Return methInfo.Invoke(methInfo, New Object() {})
    End If
  End Function
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use CodeDom to evaluate expressions. The expression in your example would be `"8 * 3"`, or `"8" + tbox.Text + "3"`.

Here's an [example](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=397265) of how to do this in VB.NET. The function is certainly more than a one liner, but calling it will be simple.

Answer (score 5):

> Can anyone solve this in one line without building a long, complex function?

Perhaps, yes, but I think a small function is much better:

```
Function Compute(a as integer, oper as String, b as integer) as integer
  If oper = "*" Then
    return a*b
  ElseIf oper = "\" Then
    Return a\b
  Else
    Throw New InvalidOperationException()
  End If
End Function
```

If you really want a one-liner you can use the `If()` function:

```
Dim i As Integer = If(oper = "*", a*b, a\b)
```

This will not check for invalid operators.

Answer (score 3):

This is confusing, are you saying you want to use multiply and divide as operators in VB.NET?

The can be accomplished with dim i as integer = 8*9

Answer (score 2):

You could eval an entire string like "8*3" using a ScriptControl:

http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Tip/18773

Pretty dangerous, though...you would need to throughly sanitize any user input to make sure it's only math they are attempting.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to know to do a similar thing, and then, a friend found the right way to do it using "Microsoft Script Control 1.0", to know how to use it, visit this link:

http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Tip/18773

I see it better than any other way :-).